# Repairing heating element and plug for old electric cooktop

Tags: electrical, kitchens, stove, old-house

I'm repairing an old Thermador TM45-1 electric cooktop (22" by 45" with two 6" burners, two 8" burners, and a griddle in the center).

It's in surprisingly good shape except for 1 of the 8" elements that is burnt out/rusted, including the wiring/connector. I've spoken to a few suppliers but it appears that direct replacement parts are discontinued or unavailable.

These elements were hard-wired (pic attached) instead of the plug-in type connectors that are more common in contemporary cooktops. Plan is to replace it with a new connector plug (possibly like this one-pic #2), but haven't been able to find reliable info to make sure I choose the right type since most new ones are "universal" but still specify brands (GE, Whirlpool, etc).

[image][image]

Other than making sure it's physically able to fit into the space under cooktop and allow the coil to plug in securely and sit level, is there anything else that I need to consider to make sure it's a safe replacement plug to use?

Thanks!

--In related info for the overall project: I've found some excellent info about replacing the heating element, since there isn't an available exact replacement part for that either.

Special thanks to Jim Stewart's answer to another question ([What effect does the number of coil turns on an electric stove heating element have?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/65587/what-effect-does-the-number-of-coil-turns-on-an-electric-stove-heating-element-h/202840#202840)) who clarified the calculation for expected resistance that can be measured and help make sure a replacement element is appropriate.

Comment: Make sure to get high temp crimps, I believe they are rated at 900f or close the standard crimps tinned copper will fail in a rather short time as the heat is above the standard crimp rating. I’ve done this with a few elements and used silver solder on others I could not fit a crimp on

Comment: Great advice - I will make sure to do that. Thanks!